# Iterate through a mongocxx query to get each key and value

Tags: mongo-cxx-driver

I am querying a collection with the following code:

```
bsoncxx::stdx::optional<bsoncxx::document::value> query_result =
collection.find_one(bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{} << "_tablename" << tableToSearch.toUtf8().constData() << "rowuuid" << UUIDToSearch.toUtf8().constData() << bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize);
if(query_result)
{

}
```

I can see from the documentation how to print the result:

```
std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(*maybe_result) << "\n";
```

But how can I Iterate through the result to get each key and its value as string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a read through the mongocxx and bsoncxx examples. You can find the example demonstrating cursor iteration here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/fc9a44325e03bb8bb166e814caeb23413b4ba7af/examples/mongocxx/query.cpp#L43-L46

However, in your example you are doing a find one, so I guess you want to iterate each field, not each document. In that case, you can see examples of walking BSON objects here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/fc9a44325e03bb8bb166e814caeb23413b4ba7af/examples/bsoncxx/view_and_value.cpp#L61-L62